# Routes and window.location - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, autocomplete

I have a search field with the same name and id inside my categories page and inside my products page.The autocomplete suggestions seems to work fine , however once I click  on search suggestion inside my search field it converts my search string to integer which is my products id .Afterwards its redirecting me to "mysite/products id"  with "No content for this menu" . I guess the issue is with my routes and my window.location inside my JS , but I cant figure it out.

Here is my code

My routes

```
Route::get('products/{id}', 'AutoCompleteController@show');
    Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@show'));
    Route::get('searchajax',array('as'=>'searchajax','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@autoComplete'));
```

Few more routes connected to Categories and Products :

```
Route::get('shop', 'ShopController@categories');// my categories page

Route::get('shop/{category_url}', 'ShopController@products');  // my products page
```

My AutoCompleteController:

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
class AutoCompleteController extends MainController {

     public function show(Product $product) {
        return view('content.products', ['product' => $product]);

   }
    public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
        $query = $request->get('term','');

        $products=Product::where('title','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();

        $data=array();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
                  $data[]=array('label'=>$product->title,'value'=>$product->id);
        }
        if(count($data)){
        return $data;}
        else{
            return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
    }}

}
```

My view in products.blade and categories.blade for my autocomplete search is the same :

```
@extends ('master') 

@section('content')   
<link href="http://demo.expertphp.in/css/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<div class="row">  
    <form class="navbar-form text-center " form method="GET" action=" ">
        <input id="search_text" placeholder=" Search products" name="search_text" type="text" value="" style="width: 400px; height: 35px; border-radius: 5px ; padding-left: 12px;"><br><br>
        <input class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value="  Search" >  
    </form>
</div>


<script> 
      $(document).ready(function () {
        src = "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
$("#search_text").autocomplete({ 

    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);

            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function( event, ui ) {

        window.location = '{{ url('shop/{category_url}')}}' + ui.item.value
    } // not sure if this is the correct way , please advise
});  
      });
</script>
```

Comment: you can try window.location = 'shop/' + ui.item.value or window.location = 'shop/' + ui.item.label

Comment: @LeonardoCabré I tried. Its not working.I got an error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Which value is for `category_url`, I think you missed to return that from `autoComplete()` method?

Comment: my {category_url} has a dynamic value...how can I return it in my autocomplete?

Comment: So may I assume that `$product->title` on is for `category_url` OR else?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question. My products table include id,categorie_id,title,article,url,imageupfated_at,created_at... there's no category_url

Comment: Then how did you fill `category_url` into your JS code: `url('shop/{category_url}')`?

Comment: That is why   I am asking for advise because no matter what I put there its not working so far

Comment: Do you have a relationship between `product` and `category`?  I guess yes, because you have `category_id` field in your products table?  And is 
`category_url` in your category table?  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `autoComplete` method:

```
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // I guess you have product->cagegory relationship, and category model
        // has a URL?
        $category_url = $product->category->url; 
        $data[]=array('label'=>$product->title,'value'=>$category_url);
    }
```

Now your autocomplete results include the category_url, so you just update your JS:

```
window.location = '{{ url("shop/" + ui.item.value) }}';
```

Comment: Check OP's comment
*My products table include id,categorie_id,title,article,url,imageupfated_at,created_at‌​... there's no category_url *. How `$product->category->url` work in your answer?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd check my answer again, note the comment explaining exactly what you are asking, and go read up on Laravel relationships.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes I have relationship of one to many between in my categorie.php  model .

Comment: Here is some of my categorie.php model code https://pastebin.com/ir8ucGYs

Comment: OK, so I can see you should be able to do `$product->category` to get category, and I see category has a `url` field.  So my answer above should work.

Comment: @I applied your answer , still doesn't work. Shouldn't I change something in my route?

Comment: What is the error, what happens?  What URL do you end up on?  You already have a route set up for `shop/{category_url}`, do you hit it?

Comment: My auto complete doesn't work now ... after changing it to   $category_url = $product->category->url; 
        $data[]=array('label'=>$product->title,'value'=>$category_url); I got an error that say "Trying to get property of non-object
in AutoCompleteController.php (line 20)"

Comment: OK, so your relationship does not seem to work. Do you have a `category` method in your `Product` model?  You do have the inverse (`products` method in `Category` model).

Comment: I guess the product->category relationship would be [`belongsTo`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

Comment: @Don'tPanic  here is my complete Product model code: https://pastebin.com/7qSnKF3S

Comment: OK - you are missing the product->category relationship.  You already have category->product, but you need the reverse.  Add it in your Product model - it should be belongsTo, see the docs.  Something like `public function category() { 
return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}`

Comment: I did as you said,its still doesn't work,I got an error related to Ajax and my auto complete suggestions  stop working

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: OK, and what is the error? If you don't see it in your browser, `storage/logs/laravel.log` will show.

Comment: Is it safe to open it?It says "The file laravel.log seems to be too large (6 Mb) to safely open. 
Opening the file could cause OutOfMemoryError, which would make the IDE unusable. Do you really want to open it?"

Comment: @Don'tPanic when I look into XHR is say "Using $this when not in object context
in Product.php (line 42)"

Comment: This is basic PHP stuff, I can't help you with that.  Look at your `products` method in your `Category` model.  Just like that, you want a `category` method in your `Product` model.  The code I provided above is correct.  [Check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).  Good luck.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I really appreciate your time and help . Its just each time I am correcting an error another one will appear. I fixed the previous one.However now when I changed my window.location = '{{ url("shop/" + ui.item.value) }}'; as you suggested , when I go to my shop page now I got this error :Use of undefined constant ui - assumed 'ui' (View: "C:\xampp\htdocs\myhero\resources\views\content\categories.blade.php)"

Comment: @Don'tPanic I posted a new question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893706/issue-with-laravel-auto-complete-search

Comment: @PioPie so none of my answers helped?